# php get input value without clicking a button or submitting it

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, html

I have an html code where the value is stored in an input with hidden as its type. I want to use that value and put it in a php variable without clicking button or anything. Just plainly get the value (because I need it when I am going to get a value from sql). MY AJAX CODE DOESN'T WORK... The value i'm trying to get is the number 45,  which can be found inside the code below.

Here is my html code (it's inside a modal and the php code is there also):

```
 <div id="CalenderModalEdit" class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-header">
               <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                   <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel2">Case Details</h4>
             </div>
             <div class="modal-body">
                <form id="antoform2" class="form-horizontal calender" role="form">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Hearing #</label>
                         <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <p style="margin-top: 8px; text-align: justify" id="title_disp"></p>
                          </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Case #</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                                <p style="margin-top: 8px; text-align: justify" id="case_id"></p>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="id_case" value="45">
                            </div>
                     </div>


                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Complainant (s)</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-9">

    <?php 
    include ("config.php");
    if(isset($_POST['userID'])) {
        $uid = $_POST['userID'];
        echo $uid;

        // Do whatever you want with the $uid

    $view = mysqli_query ($conn, "SELECT idCase, lastName, firstName, Case_idcase, Person_idPerson
                                    FROM complainant, person, bar_case
                                    WHERE Person_idPerson = idPerson AND Case_idCase = idCase AND idCase = '$uid';");

    //mysqli_close($conn);
    while ($line = mysqli_fetch_array($view)) {

?>  

?>                
                            <p style="margin-top: 8px; text-align: justify" id="comp"><?php echo $line['firstName'].' '.$line['lastName']?></p>
<?php }} mysqli_close($conn); ?>
                         </div>
                       </div>

             </form>
         </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default antoclose2" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

      </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>
```

AJAX SCRIPT:

```
        <script>

    $(document).ready(function() {
            var userID = $("id_case").attr('id');
            //alert($(this).attr('id'));
            $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "../1-secretary/calendar-hearing.php",
                        data: { userID : userID },
                        success: function(data)
                        {
                            alert("success!");
                        }
                    });
    });



    </script>
```

I want to use it in the same page. How can I do it? Please help me. Your help will be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The code is quite messy and I don't understand completely how it should work, but at first you need to change JS line to `$("#id_case").attr("value")`.

Answer (score 0):

Your (and any other) php script just generates HTML on a server where the script runs and then sends this HTML to a browser which runs on a different machine. To read something from an HTML page (which as you remember is in a browser on a different machine) you need to send some data back to the server where your script can intercept it.

The fact that HTML, php and SQL code are in the same file on the server doesn't mean that generated HTML page and php/SQL code are run on the same machine.

So you can't get the value without sending data back to the server where your script is. People were right - you need either AJAX or form submission to get the value.

Comment: Oh. Thanks for this input but every time I try the code from the internet like AJAX, it doesn't work :(